# pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: php, sql, json, postgresql

what's wrong with my query ? im sure its work a few days ago, but today i dont know why its happen. how i can solve this ?
sorry my bad english

error :
[image]

query :

```
function getUserGroupList() {
    $rulesQuery = "SELECT * FROM t_rules";
    $rulesResult = pg_query($this->DB, $rulesQuery);

    $nextQuery = '';

    while ($data = pg_fetch_array($rulesResult)) {
        $nextQuery .= ",(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_user_group_rules ugp WHERE ugp.ref_user_group = ug.id AND ugp.ref_rules = ".$data['id'].") as ".str_replace(' ', '_', $data['c_name'])."_count,(SELECT c_status FROM t_user_group_rules ugp WHERE ugp.ref_user_group = ug.id AND ugp.ref_rules = ".$data['id'].") as ".str_replace(' ', '_', $data['c_name']);
    }

    $query = "SELECT ug.id, ug.c_name $nextQuery
        FROM t_user_group ug
        WHERE ug.c_active = 1";

    $result = pg_query($this->DB, $query);
    // echo $query;
    // exit();
    $all = array();

    while ($data = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        array_push($all, $data);
    }

    echo json_encode($all);
}
```

if I echo `$query`, it will become like this

```
SELECT
   ug.id,
   ug.c_name,
   (SELECT count(*)
    FROM t_user_group_rules ugp
    WHERE ugp.ref_user_group = ug.id
       AND ugp.ref_rules = 1
   ) AS command_count,
   (SELECT c_status
    FROM t_user_group_rules ugp
    WHERE ugp.ref_user_group = ug.id
       AND ugp.ref_rules = 1
   ) AS command,
   (SELECT count(*)
    FROM t_user_group_rules ugp
    WHERE ugp.ref_user_group = ug.id
       AND ugp.ref_rules = 2
   ) AS user_count,
   (SELECT c_status
    FROM t_user_group_rules ugp
    WHERE ugp.ref_user_group = ug.id
       AND ugp.ref_rules = 2
   ) AS USER,
   (SELECT count(*)
    FROM t_user_group_rules ugp
    WHERE ugp.ref_user_group = ug.id
       AND ugp.ref_rules = 3
   ) AS executive_count,
   (SELECT c_status
    FROM t_user_group_rules ugp
    WHERE ugp.ref_user_group = ug.id
       AND ugp.ref_rules = 3
   ) AS executive,
   (SELECT count(*)
    FROM t_user_group_rules ugp
    WHERE ugp.ref_user_group = ug.id
       AND ugp.ref_rules = 4
   ) AS rekon_count,
   (SELECT c_status
    FROM t_user_group_rules ugp
    WHERE ugp.ref_user_group = ug.id
       AND ugp.ref_rules = 4
   ) AS rekon,
   (SELECT count(*)
    FROM t_user_group_rules ugp
    WHERE ugp.ref_user_group = ug.id
       AND ugp.ref_rules = 5
   ) AS ej_count,
   (SELECT c_status
    FROM t_user_group_rules ugp
    WHERE ugp.ref_user_group = ug.id
       AND ugp.ref_rules = 5
   ) AS ej,
   (SELECT count(*)
    FROM t_user_group_rules ugp
    WHERE ugp.ref_user_group = ug.id
       AND ugp.ref_rules = 12
   ) AS tes_count,
   (SELECT c_status
    FROM t_user_group_rules ugp
    WHERE ugp.ref_user_group = ug.id
       AND ugp.ref_rules = 12
   ) AS tes
FROM t_user_group ug
WHERE ug.c_active = 1;
```

Comment: You should use prepared statements for your queries in PHP.  Your current query is very hard to read, because it's obfuscated by so many concatenations.

Comment: It's also hideously insecure. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen how i can do that ? im confused.

Comment: @CraigRinger yea, i will make this secure soon

Comment: You've got a PHP problem and a SQL problem.  If you want the SQL problem fixed, which is what your title implies, then edit your question and show us the raw Postgres queries being run.

Comment: What are you trying to get with this subselect? `SELECT c_status FROM t_user_group_rules ugp` It is returning more than one row for given WHERE clause and you either need to make it return 1 row or use other method for selecting c_status; for example JOIN.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i already edited the question, i try to echo $query and that's the query. am i wrong ?

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński i want to count user group from user_group_rule based on t_rules and check the c_status in t_user_group_rules

Comment: Your query is totally illegible.  Please format it as `code` (indent each line with four spaces, etc.).

Comment: @GavindaKinandana if each of those counts can have only one c_status, then add `LIMIT 1` to this subquery and it should work. You can also try instead to do `SELECT DISTINCT c_status [..]` and it will work as long as you can have only one c_status per `count(*)`. It will return error otherwise and you can then investigate why it has more than 1. `DISTINCT` will perform worse.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński whoaa thanks sir, its work.

Answer (score 0):

If any of the `count(*)` in your query would return a value greater than 1, you will get this error.

That is because a subselect in the `SELECT` list may not return more than a single value, since it will result in a single value (if there is no result, you will get an SQL NULL).

Comment: ohh okay, i see. thanks sir. I try to follow @Lukasz's answer and its work